# Existiert die Regel »Akkusativobjekt + Verb man + da + feste Präposition, dass + ...«?

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case, relative-clause

Ich habe den folgenden Satz in einem deutschen Text gelesen.

1. > Diesen Teil **erkennt** man dar**an**, dass hier man Tischdecken auf den
   >   Tischen finden kann.

Basierend auf diesem Beispiel habe ich die folgenden Sätze geschrieben.

2. > Dieses Thema **redet** man dar**über**, dass das Problem wichtig ist.
3. > Diesen Erfolg **dankt** man da**für**, dass die Studenten eine gute Ausübung hatten.

Sind die Sätze zwei und drei richtig? Wenn ja, kann man sagen, dass die Regel `Akkusativobjekt + Verb man + da + feste Präposition, dass + ...` existiert?

Danke,
Viele Grüsse

Comment: Sentence 1 is incorrect, so you’re basing your assumption on hollow ground.

Comment: All three sentences are incorrect. So, to me, it is not clear, what you are aiming at.

Comment: Deine Grundannahme ist schon problematisch: Warum sollte man **immer** ein Akkusativ-Objekt benutzen, nur weil man das zufälligerweise mit "erkennen" tut? "Danken" zum Beispiel erfordert ein *Dativ*-Objekt: "jemande**m** danken".

Comment: Was meinst du mit der Frage »Existiert die Regel ...«? Wenn du wissen willst, ob es mindestens einen korrekten deutschen Satz gibt, den man so bilden kann, lautet die Antwort *ja*. Wenn du wissen willst, ob man alle deutschen Sätze so bilden muss, lautet die Antwort *nein*. Für alles was dazwischen liegt, lautet die Antwort »das kommt darauf an«.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich habe die Frage verstanden als "Wenn ich meinen Satz so aufbaue, stimmt er dann immer?"

Comment: @sgf: Ja, und so versteht eben jeder etwas anderes. Und genau deswegen plädiere ich dafür, die Frage als *unclear what you're asking* zu markieren und zu schließen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Satz 1 sollte heißen:

> Diesen Teil erkennt man daran, dass man hier Tischdecken auf den Tischen finden kann.

Man kann das Akkusativobjekt immer nach vorne stellen, wenn das Subjekt "man" ist.

Dafür braucht man aber immer noch ein Verb, das ein Akkusativobjekt verlangt. "Reden" verlangt keines - man kann weder sagen "Ich rede dich" noch "Ich rede das". "Danken" verlangt ebenfalls keines - man sagt "Ich danke dir", nicht "Ich danke dich".

Ebenso kommt "da" + Präposition nur in Satz 1 vor, weil "erkennen" grundsätzlich ein Präpositionalobjekt fordert, nämlich "da" + Dativ. Man sagt z.B.

> Man erkennt Vögel an ihren Flügeln.

Was genau mit Satz 2 gemeint ist, ist schwer zu sagen: Entweder ist das Thema das, worüber man redet. Dann müsste es heißen "Man redet über dieses Thema." Andernfalls ist die Tatsache, dass das Problem wichtig ist, das, worüber man redet. Dann heißt es "Man redet darüber, dass das Problem wichtig ist."

Satz 3 könnte natürlich heißen: "Diese**m** Erfolg dankt man dafür, dass die Studenten eine gute Hausübung hatten." Man kann aber einem Erfolg nicht danken. Man kann den Erfolg etwas anderem **ver**danken - "Diesen Erfolg verdankt man der Tatsache, dass die Studenten viel geübt haben".

Es gibt also keine solche Regel.

Comment: "Reden" kann sehr wohl ein Akkusativobjekt haben, z.B. kann man Unsinn reden. Aber man redet nicht ein Thema, sondern über ein Thema.

Comment: @RHa Das ist wohl eher ein Idiom. Man kann ja auch nicht "was Gescheites reden"

Comment: @sgf: Du redest **Blech.** Andere reden **Tacheles**. Und dann gibt es natürlich auch noch jene, die **irgendetwas** reden. Alle fett hervorgehobenen Satzglieder sind Akkusativobjekte.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Stimmt! Bei _Tacheles_ wissen wir das aber gar nicht so genau, das könnte ebenso ein Adverb sein. Und sonst kann _reden_ anscheinend nur ganz bestimmte Akkusativobjekte nehmen, nämlich solche, die das Gesagte herunter machen - spannend!